# How to write MySQL query where Date1 TO Date2?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way in mysql where I can do something like

> Select * FROM table WHERE (YEAR(Date) = '$year1' AND MONTH(Date) =
>   '$month1') TO (YEAR(Date) = '$year2' AND MONTH(Date) = '$month2');

[image]

I am new to programming and would really appreciate any help or suggestions.Thank you.

Comment: you want date between this two dynamic dates data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$year1 $month1', '%Y %m') AND
                   STR_TO_DATE('$year2 ($month2+1)', '%Y %m')
```

Actually, using `BETWEEN` might include the first day of the following month which you don't really want.  In this case, you can just use `>` and `<` operators:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Date >= STR_TO_DATE('$year1 $month1', '%Y %m') AND
      Date < STR_TO_DATE('$year2 ($month2+1)', '%Y %m')
```

From [this resource](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) we find that:

> The STR_TO_DATE() sets all incomplete date values, which are not provided by the input string, to zero.

If you wanted to get the range February 1, 2016 to March 31, 2016 (inclusive), then my solution says take any date *on* or *after* February 1 and *before* *April* 1.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me an empty result set I have updated my question with my table structure.This is what I tried SELECT *
FROM billing_all
WHERE date > STR_TO_DATE('2015 6', '%Y %m') AND
      date < STR_TO_DATE('2016 6', '%Y %m');

Comment: This query won't return anything because you don't have any records which are earlier than June 2016.

Comment: I have data for dates 2016-06-09 and 2016-06-10 which should be returned as it falls between our range which june 2015 to june 2016.Why did it not return this data then?

Comment: You didn't follow my query.  If you want to include June-2016, then you should use `< STR_TO_DATE('2016 7', '%Y %m')` _or_ you can use `<= STR_TO_DATE('2016 6', '%Y', '%m')`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2')